# About the errors that appears due to Laravel caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am about to upload my Laravel project into online server and I had an important question about that..

- In development phase , I often have many bugs about Laravel caching and after hours of trying solving them , I realize that I should have cleared the cache by artisan command.
  So my question is , Should I make a Cron job in the server to automatically clear the cache by

`php artisan optimize:clear` ???

Comment: Not. You must run php artisan optimize one time after each deploy.

Comment: automatically clearing the cache using a cron job in a production environment not recommended. Instead, adopt a more controlled approach to cache management and only clear the cache manually or conditionally when necessary, such as during maintenance or code deployments

Comment: Locally you should avoid running the command `php artisan optimize:clear` as it's dev environment and on production it should be run once new changes are deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Maksim answer the best thing to do is to call

> php artisan optimize

when you deploy your code, that is sufficient.